# Smart Search - Directly to a Page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, search

I was wondering if there is a way to create a search that takes the input and will go directly to a related page.

For instance: If I were to limit the search for just movies and typed, 'Terminator', it would bring me to the profile page of the 'Terminator' directly instead of searching a list and returning different results.

Something like if:
search_input = n, n = "movie_title" true then go to "blah.com/movie_title" if false return "No Result"

Hopefully that makes sense?

If anyone can help or knows of any plugin or script or something, that'd be really appreciate. Thanks all.

Comment: you mean like googles "im feeling lucky" feature?

Comment: jQuery UI Autocomplete sounds like it can do this

Comment: yeah, just like the 'im feeling lucky' feature. is there a way to do this?

Comment: yes. just do the search as normal, and pick one of the results to use. redirect them to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll use an autocomplete plugin like:

-http://textextjs.com/manual/examples/autocomplete.html

or

-http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Because your thought have a problem When do you know an input is right to redirect? I mean "Terminator" is valid for the title "Terminator 1" (For example) but is right "Termitanor"? or "reminatort"?

Comment: Is it possible to use <?php the_title() ; ?> or some other function to generate a list of 'Post Titles' to be used as Tags instead of having to type out all of the 'availableTags'?

Comment: The best way is generate the avaliable titles in a json and get that json with jquery.